# Angularjs ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

ng-class is not working with multiple condition. Apply a class when both conditions are true

Here open and active class should apply when childActive is equal to header and list items is not empty

```
<li ng-class="{'open':list.items.length&&childActive==header,
'active':list.items.length&&childActive==header}"
         ng-repeat="list in listEntities">
```

Comment: plunker or fiddle demo ?

Comment: I suggest to add a function in case of having complex expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some other issue. The following, with multiple conditions, works:

```
<input ng-model="highlightEven" type="checkbox">
<div ng-repeat="item in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']"
     ng-class="{even: $index % 2 === 0 && highlightEven}">{{item}}</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QQecUVMQ8I3Bf7U7BDl6?p=preview)

Comment: It is also not working with two classes:<div ng-repeat="item in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']" ng-class="{even: $index % 2 === 0 && highlightEven, even-size: $index % 2 === 0 && highlightEven}">{{item}}</div>

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking (_if_ you're asking)

Comment: Put `even-size` in single-quotes: `"{'even-size': $index % 2 === 0 && highlightEven}"`

Comment: Thanks New Dev. Now it's working fine : http://plnkr.co/edit/ULJlInfSlK7SIf3o8DOG?p=preview